# Why $- \int \frac{du}{1-u^2}$ is not $-\frac{1}{2}\ln |1-u^2|$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Why $- \int \frac{du}{1-u^2}$ is not $-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-u^2|$ ?

The context of this question is the integral of the csc

$$u  = \cos x$$

Why the above integral is not  true and instead we have to use:

$$\frac{1}{1-u^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+u} +\frac{1}{1-u}\right)$$

Comment: You need a $u$ in the numerator to get your answer.

Comment: Because $\frac{d}{du}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-u^2|\right)=\frac{u}{1-u^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key Point: $$\int f(\color{blue}{a}x+b) dx=\frac{1}{\color{blue}{a}}F(\color{blue}{a}x+b)+c$$
Where, $F(x)$ is antiderivative of $f(x)$ and $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

For instance,
$$- \int \frac{du}{1-\color{green}{2}u}=-\frac{1}{\color{green}{2}}\ln|1-\color{green}{2}u|+c_1$$

In your question, $$\int \frac{du}{1-u^\color{green}{2}}$$
$2$ is power of $u$, not coefficient. So,
$$\int \frac{du}{1-u^\color{green}{2}}\ne-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-u^2|+c_2$$

You can do that answer in case of,
$$\int \frac{udu}{1-u^2}{=\frac{1}2\int \frac{2udu}{1-u^2}\\
=\frac{1}2\int \frac{d(u^2)}{1-u^2}\\=-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-u^2|+c_3}$$